# Application icon does not open last used activity

Tags: android

In some situations (I do not know exactly what causes this to happen),
if I start my app, open another (here AaaActivity) activity and then click the home button to get to the phone home view, and then click the app icon from there, it starts in the application home view, instead of starting in the last open activity.

Why is this and what do I need to do to make it return to the last used activity (AaaActivity)?

Here is an excerpt from the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="x.y.app.android.SsssActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleBarNoBackground">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="x.y.app.android.AaaActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/activity_videoview"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="x.y.app.android.AaaName" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: can you put your `AndroidManifest.xml` here?

Comment: need to see some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple tasks can be held in Android OS in the background at once. However, if the OS is running many background tasks at the same time, the system might begin destroying background activities in order to recover memory, causing the activity states to be lost. This is OS design and you can't prevent it. What you can do is saving your state so that you can retrieve it next time. [Tasks in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)